# Chrome is flashing white space on hover items

Tags: html, css

Site loads looks fine on Safari and Firefox but is behaving very oddly in google chrome. Chrome appears to be struggling to load the page and animations are very jerky/white-flashy. Not sure where I went wrong it was looking fine in Chrome before I moved it from local to hosting.

Here is a snippet of the menu for instance where on hover it will flash white in chrome. Plus it seems chrome wont load what is not in its viewport.

http://tjsbowties.com/

```
body {
position: relative;
background: #fffdfa;
font-size: 16px;

}
.t-menu {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 3em;
height: 13em;

z-index: 99;

}

.t-ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.t-menu-ul {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
max-width: 80em;
height: 13em;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding: 1em 2em 0 2em;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.t-menu-ul li {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 8em;
text-align: center;
}

a.t-link {
position: relative;
font-family: 'Caviar Dreams', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
color: #fffdfa;
padding-bottom: 0.6em;
border-bottom: 0.4em solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
cursor: pointer;

transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

a.t-link:hover {
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 0.4em solid #e7b32c;
}

.t-hero {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
min-height: 50em;
max-height: 67.5em;
border: 2em solid #fffdfa;
border-top: 3em solid #fffdfa;

background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(18, 5, 7, 0.4), rgba(18, 5, 7, 0.4)), url('/img/fl-hero-a.jpg');
background-blend-mode: multiply;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

transition: all 0.2s ease;
}


<nav class="t-menu">
        <ul class="t-ul t-menu-ul">
            <li>
                <a class="t-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/tjsbowties" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="t-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/tjs_bowties/" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="logo-list-item">
                <img class="img-responsive margin-auto logo-img" src="/img/tj-bowties-logo.svg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="t-link page-scroll" href="#about">
                    About
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="t-link" href="https://squareup.com/store/tjs-bowties/">
                    Order
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that's giving you issues?

Comment: Alright added a sample of code where the problem occurs, but it is site wide

Comment: I think this is because your page size is too large (~6MB), which means if you hover somewhere when page is loading (the loading may cost a lot of time), the hover animation may not work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was found. By changing the modals to have a css visibility: visible and visibility: hidden my flashing issues are gone. The issue was too many swipers were being initialized at once.